# Online International Schools

Tags: discussion

I don't know if this kind of questions is acceptable on the site. I would like to get a list of some US/Canada accredited online schools that are known to accept students from outside of US/Canada namely from Libya (North Africa).

I have two Canadian children who are native English speakers, the older attended junior and senior kindergarten in Canada. The younger attended a early education program in the same city in Ontario.

The idea is to get the curriculum books/resources either online or by mail. The exams should be conducted online, but other practical solutions are welcome.

Comment: I agree with Karl, but I'll offer this: I know K12 helps US military families outside of the states in this way, but if you are not a US citizen and military I believe the curriculum (and services) are still available outside the US - but you have to pay for it.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have sent them an email and asked for the fees but I've never received a reply for weeks!

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, asking for a list of external resources is off topic for this site.